Sync vs Async function execution time confusion
I am struggling to understand why an asynchronous function with some calculations takes such a long time to execute. I have simplified my code like so:
const syncCalc = () => {
    let v = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
        //emtpy loop
        v += i
    }
    return v;
}

const asyncCalc = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        let v = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
            //emtpy loop
            v += i
        }
        resolve(v);
    })


console.time('syncCalc');
console.log("Result:", syncCalc());
console.timeEnd('syncCalc');

console.log('------------')

console.time('asyncCalc');
asyncCalc().then(v => console.log("Result:", v));
console.timeEnd('asyncCalc');

The result of the above code run in node is:
Result: 49999995000000
syncCalc: 27.659ms
------------
asyncCalc: 14.152ms
Result: 49999995000000


The first part (i.e. 27 ms) makes perfect sense. It takes a while for the calculation to finish in a synchronous environment.
What I don't get is why it takes 14 ms to get past the asyncCalc function. Shouldn't the jump from console.time('asyncCalc'); to console.timeEnd('asyncCalc'); be instant as we DO NOT wait for the asyncCalc().then(... to execute?
Why, then, does this take under a millisecond to get from time to timeEnd?
const asyncTimeout = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(49999995000000), 1000)
    })

console.time('asyncCalc');
asyncTimeout().then(v => console.log("Result:", v));
console.timeEnd('asyncCalc');

// asyncCalc: 0.962ms
// Result: 49999995000000



Can someone explain this to me please?

There is nothing asynchronous about asyncCalc. The Promise is created synchronously, meaning it's executor function is also executed synchronously. Promises are for making things that are already asynchronous (such as setTimeout, fetch, etc), easier to deal with, not for making synchronous code run in the background.

There has to be hundreds of duplicates to this question

@NickParsons In that case how come the asyncCalc doesn't take the same amount of time to execute as syncCalc? Why only half the time?

@codemonkey potentially some sort of engine optimisation. Try running these snippets independently of each other or the async one first.

Yep, you're right.
